# Scraping 5 characters off a webpage using sed or something better?

Tags: web-scraping, awk, sed

I have a downloaded webpage I would like to scrape using sed or awk. I have been told by a colleague that what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible with sed and maybe this is probably correct seeing as he is a bit of a linux guru.

What I am trying to achieve:

I am trying to scrape a locally stored html document for every value within this html label which apppears hundreds of times on a webpage..

For example:

```
<label class="css-l019s7">54321</label>
<label class="css-l019s7">55555</label>
```

This label class never changes, so it seems the perfect point to do scraping and get the values:

54321
55555

There are hundreds of occurences of this data and I need to get a list of them all.

As sed probably isn't capable of this, I would be forever greatful if someone could demonstrate AWK or something else?

Thank you.

---

Things I've tried:

```
sed -En 's@(^.*<label class=\"css-l019s7\">)(.*)(</label>.*$)@\2@gp' TS.html
```

This code above managed to extract about 40 of the numbers out of 320. There must be a little bug in this sed command for it to work partially.

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: There are dozens of web-scraping tools that allows to get HTML node text content

Comment: Sed should be able to do the job - sed -rn 's@(^.*<label class=\"css-l019s7\">)(.*)(</label>.*$)@\2@gp' htmlfile

Comment: Thanks Raman, unfortunately I'm getting the error sed: illegal option -- r (might be something to do with using MacOS)

Comment: while sed should be able to do the job, remember sed is used to perform inplace substitution above everything else. Awk is more suited for complex text processing. Grep might also do for scraping, probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a parser like `xmllint`:

   ```
   xmllint --html --recover --xpath '//label[@class="css-l019s7"]/text()' TS.html
   ```
2. As an interest in `sed` was expressed (note that html can use newlines instead of spaces, for example, so this is not very robust):

   ```
   sed 't a
   s/<label class="css-l019s7">\([^<]*\)/\
   \1\
   /;D
   :a
   P;D' TS.html
   ```
3. Using `awk`:

   ```
   awk '$1~/^label class="css-l019s7"$/ { print $2 }' RS='<' FS='>' TS.html
   ```

   or:

   ```
   awk '$1~/^[\t\n\r ]*label[\t\n\r ]/ &&
   $1~/[\t\n\r ]class[\t\n\r ]*=[\t\n\r ]*"css-l019s7"[\t\n\r ]*([\t\n\r ]|$)/ {
       print $2
   }' RS='<' FS='>' TS.html
   ```

Comment: AWESOME. You cracked it. Examples 2 and 3 all worked. Thank you so much and to everyone who tried nailing this.

Answer (score 0):

*someone could demonstrate AWK or something else?*

This task seems for me as best fit for using *CSS selector*. If you are allowed to install tools you might use [Element Finder](https://github.com/keeganstreet/element-finder) for this following way:

```
elfinder -s "label.css-l019s7"
```

which will search for `label`s with class `css-l019s7` in files in current directory.

Comment: I don't have Element Finder installed on my MacBook and looks like it needs NodeJS etc to run. Thank you very much for your input though, looks like it would have been good.

Answer (score 0):

with `grep` you can get the values

```
grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{5})' file
54321
55555
```

with `awk` you can concrete where the values are, here in the lines with `label` at the beginning and at the end:

```
awk '/^<label|\/label>$/ {if (match($0,/[[:digit:]]{5}/)) { pattern = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print pattern}}' file
54321
55555
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately these examples will not work though. The first example is pulling thousands of 5 digit numbers from this 2.6MB html I have and only a small percentrage are the ones I need.

Comment: I would be more specific about the class identifier maybe /^<label|\/label>$/ && /css-l019s7/

Answer (score 0):

using GNU awk and gensub:

```
awk '/label class/ && /css-l019s7/ { str=gensub("(<label class=\"css-l019s7\">)(.*)(</label>)","\\2",$0);print str}' file
```

Search for lines with "label class" and "css=1019s7". Split the line into three sections and substitute the line for the second section, reading the result into a variable str. Print str.

Comment: Looks incredibly promising, but I'm receiving an error! Probably this version of awak on MacOS 

awk: calling undefined function gensub